# IOS 9 - UIButton on subview does not fire IBAction outlet

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton, ios9

I've been struggling with this for a couple of days now and haven't been able to pinpoint the cause of my problem, as the title says, a UIButton on a subview is not firing the IBAction outlet when "clicked".

Let me elaborate, I'm working on a "tinder-like" app, where I'm using [this third party library](https://github.com/Yalantis/Koloda). I'm implementing customized views which have buttons and other controllers in them. The buttons in these "Cards" are not firing their IBAction outlets.

As far as I can tell, the library does the following:

Stacks 3 "DraggableViews" on top of each other, each draggable view has 2 child views, one is the content view, where my custom view lives, and the other is an overlay view, which has an image view on top. The draggable views use two gesture recognizer to do its thing, the first one is a tap gesture that calls a delegate method to handle tap events in the card (in their example its used to show a browser view). The second gesture is a pan gesture used to implement the swipe functionality of the card.

I've done my homework and have tried a few different solutions but I can't get the IBAction to fire. I've tried the following:

- Use the parent view of the DraggableViews to disable the gesture recognizer when the touch event is triggered on a button. - This works (gesture is disabled) but the IBAction is not fired. on the case of the pan gesture, I am no longer able to "swipe" the card when touching the button and the tap event does not hit a breakpoint in the delegate method mentioned above. In the UI, my button reacts to the touch as it animates, but its outlet in the view controller fails to hit a breakpoint. I've disabled this as so:

  ```
  //- Called when each DraggableView is visible (not called for view at index 0, but works alright for debugging in the mean time)
  func koloda(koloda: KolodaView, didShowCardAtIndex index: UInt) {
   let subviews = koloda.subviews
   for subview in subviews {
      if let recognizers = subview.gestureRecognizers {
          for gesture in recognizers {
              if gesture is UIPanGestureRecognizer || gesture is UITapGestureRecognizer{
                  //- Also tried setting this to false but nothing.
                  gesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false 
                  gesture.delegate = self
              }
          }
      }
  }

  //- On the gestureRecognizerDelegate
  func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
     if touch.view is UIButton {
       return false
     } else {
       return true
     }
  }
  ```
- Implemented a tap gesture on the button programmatically, On viewDidLoad I add the action to the tap gesture but this does not trigger the outlet either.
- Programmatically set the userInteractionEnabled property of the ImageView to True hoping that this will allow the touch event to go through the responder chain (although I read in another post that this would have the opposite effect?).

I've also checked in the storyboard that all the relevant views and controllers in my custom view have the userInteractionEnabled option enabled.

I don't know if its relevant, but my custom view lives in a xib file, when I pass the view to the library I do it by instantiating the view controller and passing passing over its view, as so:

```
if let vc = spiViewConntroller {
        return vc.view
    }
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers!

**EDIT:**
Continuing with my search for truth, I've completely removed the overlay view from the library, inspecting my custom views on the UI debugger i can see that the overlay view and its ImageView are no longer there. The button still does not fire its outlet so I can assume that the overlay view is not causing this issue.

I've forked the Koloda library and created a branch with a [demo example](https://github.com/DanielOrmeno/Koloda/tree/StackOverflowDemo), the branch name is "StackOverflowDemo". I've added a custom view with one button, I've created two outlets in its view controller where I'm changing the title of the button (which works) on view did load. I've also disabled the two gestures on the button to replicate what i've currently got in my app. *If you do clone this down you'll need to swipe the first card off as the card at index 0 wont have the gestures disabled.*

I'll keep digging, hopefully someone can pinpoint what I'm doing wrong!

Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Daniel. 
Your issue is that you don't add your view controller as child to view controller which operates with Koloda. In the result your vc.view is shown, because Koloda retains it, but nobody retains your view controller, so you are losing important lifecycle methods and it gets deallocated.

The approach your trying to use is called Container View Controller. Apple has suggestion about its implementation here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html

Simple implementation here:

```
- (void) displayContentController: (UIViewController*) content {
   [self addChildViewController:content];
   content.view.frame = [self frameForContentController];
   [self.view addSubview:self.currentClientView];
   [content didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

Comment: Hello Eugene, Thank you for your response, this makes a lot of sense. I found a stack overflow question that suggested this solution, but looking into the code I'm not completely sure on how to add my view controller to the draggable view without modifying the koloda library. 

I'm using a ViewController that holds an instance of koloda view, would a solution be to add the my custom view controller as a child of the actual koloda view? I'll read more on Container View controller. Thanks again for your response.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found my answer. After digging some more bit i was able to solve this. However my solution feels dirty and I'm unsure if it breaks the MVC pattern.

I think my issue is that my custom View Controller for my xib file is somehow lost or unable to respond to these events. When creating the views to be displayed as the content of the draggable card, I was creating an instance of my view controller and returning its view. What's weird to me is that the ViewDidLoad method of the view controller was doing its job when the view was loaded (i.e. changing values of outlets).

**Solution:**
I removed the file owner from the lib, created a custom class that inherits from UIView, say *MyCustomUIView* and moving the view controller logic, its outlets and actions to that class. Then on the xib file, I linked the content view to *MyCustomUIView*. However this solution feels dirty as I'd expect the view's view controller to handle all the logic. Might need to do a bit more reading on nib and reusable views.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest a way, that can help you to detect the problem. Use the debugger view in xcode when the simulator is running. It will show you the hierarchy of views in 3-D mode, which can help you in finding out the issue.
How to use debuggin view:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/ExaminingtheViewHierarchy.html

Comment: Hello Ray_Soham, thank you for your suggestion. I've used the view debugger to verify that there are no views in the way, the only views that seem to sit on top of the button is the overlay view mentioned in my question, this view contains a UIImageView that covers all the its parent. After finding this I tried setting its **userInteractionEnabled** property to true but this didn't fix the issue.